# .NET tells me TypeLoadException: violates the constraint of type parameter 'T' while my code clearly doesn't violate it

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to initialize an object of `DataEditor<Student>`, where my `DataEditor<T>` class implements `interface IDataEditor<T> where T :  IEditableObject`.

```
DataEditor<Student> editor = GetEditorFor(student);
```

During runtime, I got a TypeLoadException saying:
*GenericArguments[0], 'Namespace.Data.Student', on 'Namespace.IDataEditor`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.* The exception happens on the line above, before it even goes inside the GetEditorFor method.

The only constraint on T is `IEditableObject`, and my `Student` class clearly implements it (I double checked the interface spelling, namespace, etc.), and also the compiler doesn't give me any error, so I have no idea why this error happens on runtime.

If I remove the `IEditableObject` constraint, the code runs without this exception, but my logic depends on the class being an `IEditableObject`, so it is not an option.

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

These pages seems to be related, but I still don't know the solution

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/270717/reflection-emit-chokes-on-method-type-parameters
- http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/478595-reflection-generics-could-anyone-confirm-deny-bug

Is this a bug in .NET? Has anyone found a workaround?

Edit: declaration as requested

```
public class DataEditor<T> : ViewModel, IDataEditor<T> where T :  IEditableObject

public interface IDataEditor<T> : IDataEditor 
    where T :  IEditableObject
```

Comment: Could you paste the class declaration on both IDataEditor and DataEditor?

Comment: Are all of these classes/interfaces in the same assembly? Can you reproduce the issue with a simple repro (starting with File->New Project in VS)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with empty classes. Can you post GetEditorFor()?

Comment: GetEditorFor() just return new stuff. In anycase, the exception happens before it steps in GetEditorFor(), and changing it into return null doesn't change any result

Comment: This could be a versioning problem. Delete and rebuild _all_ assemblies. Double=check you're not referencing something on an odd Path

Comment: @henk: I have deleted an rebuilt, the problem remains.. What do you mean by odd path?

Comment: Also check if there is no older versions registered in the GAC... When exception happens check out Debug->Modules for strange module locations.

Comment: Have you tried to build and execute it under VS 2010? Right now I have similar exception under VS 2012 SP1 but in VS 2010 everything is OK

Comment: Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to check if the "same" assembly has been loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

My project could not build because of the same error. Even if I did not use any of this generic typed class. Its assembly was just referenced.

When I delete the `accessor` file of it, problem solved. If you do not need `accessor`, deleting it may be a solution.

This answer may useful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

What happens is that `Student` does not implement `IEditableObject`, the `GetEditorFor` method probably has a `where` clause where `T` must be `IEditableObject`, and the `T` that you are passing is `Student`and not `IDataEditor`.

That's why you're getting this error, you're violating the method signature sending a `T` that is not IEditableObject.

You should either implement `IEditableObject`into the `Student`class, or remove the `where T : IEditableObject` clause.

Comment: The OP clearly states that the `Student` class implements `IEditableObject` and that removing the type constraint is an option neither.